# flutter setJavaScriptEnabled setWebChromeClient

Tags: webview, android-webview, flutter, flutter-dependencies

how to enable flutter_webview_plugin 0.1.5 to enable javascript and process javascript came from webpage ? here is the code in android

```
    mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.activity_main_webview);
    WebSettings webSettings = mWebView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    mWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
    mWebView.loadUrl("http://192.168.0.5/table.php");
```

how to make it works in flutter with flutter_webview_plugin  ? thank you

Comment: Currently there is no such option for setting `WebChromeClient` and `WebSettings`. You can enable and evaluate javascript in the plugin.

Answer (score 0):

In the below example, javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted is doing the same thing, enabling the javascript in flutter.

```
MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text("Foxhillbazaar.com"),
        ),
        body: Center(
          child: WebView(
            initialUrl: 'https://www.foxhillbazaar.com/',
            javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
            onWebViewCreated: (WebViewController webViewController) {
              _controller = webViewController;
            },
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
```